# AWS GreenGrass network data usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, lte, aws-iot-greengrass

Does anyone know what is the expected data usage and patterns for Greengrass?

We're using GG v2.9.2 currently with connected devices on 4G LTE modems and seeing a bit of variety across different installations but broadly, we see 1 - 10 MB a day that we cannot easily attribute to anything else on the device (other applications, component code, etc.).

We've run a comparison of with/without Greengrass (no components, no other applications) Basically, we had GG turned off for a few days (4 - 7), then turned it back on and usage spiked to ~100MB.

Is there data monitoring or throttling patterns we should be following?